# Who are the rulers of the different lands in "The Shannara Chronicles"?

Tags: shannara-chronicles

In *The Shannara Chronicles* (TV series) the four lands have been mentioned. It is never clearly mentioned that who are the rulers of those lands.

Who are the rulers of those four lands in the TV series?

Comment: From Movies & TV [Who are the rulers of Four Lands in The Shannara Chronicles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84833/who-are-the-rulers-of-four-lands-in-the-shannara-chronicles)

Comment: @AnkurRathee has there been any prove that the rulers in the books are same as rulers in the TV series or are they different

Comment: Not seen the show and not familiar with the book. Shared link fo what I found on the sister site for the heads-up.

Comment: "ruler" is a fuzzy thing, even in the books.  There is a Westland, Southland, Eastland, and Northland, but these are simply general regions where one of the five races tended to settle, with Paranor in the middle.  The Elves in Westland is the largest and best organized "kingdom" - most of the other major powers act more like city-states with surrounding territory.  Earlier in the timeline the Warlock Lord Brona ruled in the Northland.  Later on the Federation will assemble and rule Southland, along with anything else they can grab.